# How can I uniquely identify different GVim instances?

Tags: x11, vim, gvim, i3

With `gnome-terminal`, I can use the `--role` command line argument to make the new terminal window uniquely identifiable by the window manager or other applications, for example:

```
gnome-terminal --role=irc
```

This sets the X window role to "irc", as displayed by `xprop`:

```
WM_WINDOW_ROLE(STRING) = "foo"
```

Is there a way to do the same with GVim? I have combed through `gvim --help` and Googled to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xdotool` to set window's `WM_WINDOW_ROLE` property:

```
$ xdotool set_window --role <ROLE_STRING> <WINDOW_ID>
```

You can find `WINDOW_ID` by `PID`:

```
$ xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid <PID>
```

Note that there is a harmless bug message printed in `xdotool 2.x` when using this method:

```
$ xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid 16076
Can't consume 1 args; are only 0 available. This is a bug.
23068675
```

You can use [xdotool 3.x](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) to get rid of this bug.

That being said, one could create a custom wrapper to start a `gvim` instance, wait for a window to show up and set a new role string on it. It could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

role="$1"
shift

gvim --nofork "$@" &
pid="$!"
window_id=

while true; do
    window_id=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid "$pid" 2>&1 | tail -1)
    case $window_id in
    ''|*[!0-9]*) continue ;;
    *) break ;;
    esac
done

xdotool set_window --role "$role" "$window_id"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./gvim.sh FANTASTIC-NEW-ROLE <FILENAME> <OTHER-GVIM-PARAMS> <...>
```

This line:

```
window_id=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid "$pid" 2>&1 | tail -1)
```

will work well with both `xdotool 2.x` and `3.x`. It takes some time from starting a `gvim` process to window being shown so either while loop like here or `sleep()` is necessary. `--nofork` option is needed to be able to get `gvim` instance PID. Portable way for checking if variable contains a number is copied from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951175/3691891).

If you already use some kind of hook on newly created windows such as [devilspie](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/) this code may not work for you. `xdotool` must be used with `--onlyvisible` because a new instance of `gvim` will create 2 windows but only one visible. If `devilspie` will, for example, move `gvim` window to a different workspace it will not be visible any more.

Comment: This is an unfortunately complicated but none the less awesome answer! I will try it out as soon as possible